# Как написать условие выбора?

Tags: mysql

Есть код

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = 7260;
```

Как написать, чтобы выбрал не только из 7260, у меня около 5 айдишников. У меня: 7260, 21,9551, 7345.

Comment: Ничего не понял.Какие id ты именно хочешь вибрать?

Comment: Как написать что бы выбрал не только из 7260, у меня около 5 айдишников. У меня: 7260, 21,9551, 7345.

В принципе вопрос написан ясно, я могу выбрать по одному, как выбрать по нескольким. Я думаю "каким" это не принципиально нужные я подставлю сам, вопрос как прописать нескольк осразу.

Comment: посмотри оператор LIKE ,может это то что ты хочешь

Comment: "Около пяти",- это сильно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id IN (7260, 21,9551, 7345)
```

Comment: спасибо !!!!

Comment: Нет, ну сам бы мог и до тупого варианта додуматься:
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = 7260 OR id = 21 OR id = 9551  OR id = 7345